# Javascript - Reading file in client directory

Tags: javascript, readfile

I'm a new programmer that learn javascript, Im new in js actually. 
I have a task that require a web page able to read file in client directory. I've got some js code :

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ReadWeight() {
        var filePath = "file:///D:/Text.txt";
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.open("GET",filePath,false);
        xmlhttp.send(null);
        var fileContent = xmlhttp.responseText; 

        alert(fileContent);
    }

    ReadWeight();
</script>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

When I save this code in my directory and access it by this link, It works well.

```
file:///D:/test.html
```

But when I put it in my localhost and I access it, the JS doesn't works.

Does my code incorrect when in web server?
Please help me out.

Comment: if I read your code correctly... you're hoping to read a file on the client's machine from your server.  If so you can't do this - it would be a major security violation.  However you can provide an input of type="file" that would allow the user to select a file to upload.

Comment: thank you @scunliffe . I got the idea. My given task is read the file periodically every seconds. The web app intended to show the every the file's changes. I'll use the "setTimeout".

In my opinion, using type="file" only read the file once. Am I miss understand, or is there any solution for the scenario?

Comment: I'm a bit confused about your requirements... do you really need to read a remote file every second? that seems very "expensive" and I suspect the file doesn't change that often.  That said if the remote file on the "client" is really another server... then maybe you can access the file via an AJAX call to a remote server.  However if you are trying to repeatedly read a file from an end-users personal computer you simply won't be able to do it for security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Might I suggest using an error console to display the error so people know how to help you? =] And paste it in your query

Download something like firebug and see if a request is being made (for FireFox)

Comment: thank you @user2464810 for your suggestion. I do it in my browser with firebug. After i run the Console, i found one Error:

NS_ERROR_DOM_BAD_URI: Access to restricted URI denied
[Break On This Error]  
xmlhttp.send(null);

and I don't know how to fix it, help me out please :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you would rather want to access the file via the http:// protocol, instead of file://

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can only read client files using an `<input type="file">` element. Once you get the file you can read it multiple times:

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>File Refresh</title>
  <script src="filerefresh.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <input id="fileInput" type="file">
  <pre id="fileDisplay"></pre>
</body>
</html>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
(function() {
    var sleepInterval = 1000; // 1 second
    var fileInput;
    var fileDisplay;
    var reader;
    var id = undefined;
    function initialize() {
        fileInput = document.getElementById("fileInput");
        fileDisplay = document.getElementById("fileDisplay");
        reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onloadend = function() {
            fileDisplay.innerHTML = reader.result;
            reschedule();
        };
        fileInput.addEventListener("change", readFile);
    }
    function reschedule() {
        if (id !== undefined) {
            clearTimeout(id);
        }
        id = setTimeout(readFile, sleepInterval);
    }
    function readFile() {
        reader.readAsText(fileInput.files[0]);
    }

    window.onload = initialize;
})();
```